# Windows Phone 8.1 - Exit() method not working

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

My app allows pinning of secondary tiles, which can then be used to launch the app.
The behaviour I am trying to achieve is this: -

- If the app is already running when a secondary tile is clicked, it launches a URI and leaves the app running
- If the app was not running when the secondary tile is clicked, it launches the URI and then calls the Exit() method to exit the app (so that the user doesn't see an extra app appear in the app switching view).

The code I am using to do this within OnLaunched() in app.xaml.cs, as shown below.

```
    protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
#if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
#endif

       // Check to see if app has been launched from a secondary tile 
       if (e.Kind==ActivationKind.Launch && e.TileId != "App")
       {
           //If so then launch Uri passed from tile
           var uri = new Uri(e.Arguments);
           Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

           //If launched from a secondary tile, then close the app if it wasn't already running
           if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.NotRunning)
           {
               Exit();
           }


       }

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null)
        {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            // TODO: change this value to a cache size that is appropriate for your application
            rootFrame.CacheSize = 1;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
            {
                // TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (rootFrame.Content == null)
        {
            // Removes the turnstile navigation for startup.
            if (rootFrame.ContentTransitions != null)
            {
                this.transitions = new TransitionCollection();
                foreach (var c in rootFrame.ContentTransitions)
                {
                    this.transitions.Add(c);
                }
            }

            rootFrame.ContentTransitions = null;
            rootFrame.Navigated += this.RootFrame_FirstNavigated;

            // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
            // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
            // parameter
            if (!rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SignInPage), e.Arguments))
            {
                throw new Exception("Failed to create initial page");
            }
        }

        // Ensure the current window is active
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

When I run this in the emulator it works exactly as required.
However, when I run it on my device (Nokia 925), the app does not exit when launched from secondary tile, so there is always an app window left in the task switcher view, even if it was not running before.

**EDIT**  I've tried calling the Exit() method on it's own in OnLaunched() and it exits correctly.  I can only assume that it's the 'if' check to see whether the app is running that isn't working, and hence isn't calling Exit()

```
 if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.NotRunning)
```

Any ideas what's going on and how to get the phone to behave like the emulator does?

Comment: I tried calling the Exit() method in the OnLaunched event handler on my app running on a Lumia 1520 and the application does exit.

Comment: I tried just calling the Exit() method and it works. It seems like it's the  if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.NotRunning) logic that isn't working then.... Strange.

Comment: I'm glad my comment helped.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the info. I still have the problem though.  Any idea why the Exit() inside the if statement would run ok on the emulator but not on the phone?  I'm very confused.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so this wasn't quite the problem I thought it was.

It turns out the Exit() was fine, but my If statement wasn't correct.
In the emulator, this line catches all instances of the app being closed:

```
if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.NotRunning)
```

But on the phone, it was also throwing up ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated and ApplicationExecutionState.ClosedByUser

I'm not sure why closing the app manually in the emulator still returns NotRunning rather than ClosedByUser, but that was the issue.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

If you develop an app for windows phone 8.1 using windows runtime by default when you exit the app, the app goes in bachground.
as far as i know it's not possible to close the app.

Comment: The Exit() method, or Application.Exit(), does exit the app.  It works correctly in the 8.1 emulator.  It also works correctly on the phone if I just use Exit() on its own, but for some reason doesn't work when it's inside the if statement.  I guess that implies it may be the if statement that's the problem.